# Check for uploaded file type wordpress way for multiple uploads

Tags: front-end

I have a form in the frontend that lets the user upload multiple images and other file types as needed. To process multiple files array I have followed [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39753/creating-a-multi-file-upload-form-on-the-front-end-for-attachments#answer-39760) and here is the relevant.

**PHP**

```
global $post;
if ($_FILES) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
            'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
            'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
            'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );

            $_FILES = array("upload" => $file);
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $newupload = wp_insert_attachment($file,$post->ID);
            }                                   
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML** Please note that my form allows multiple images array eg. `upload[]`

```
<form method="post" id="attachment--form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" multiple="true" name="upload[]">
<?php wp_nonce_field('upload_attachments_nonce','secure_upload'); ?>
<input type="submit" id="upload_attachments_button" name="upload_attachments" value="UPLOAD">
<form>
```

---

I would like to check filetype using native wordpress functions [wp_check_filetypes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype), The codex doesnot say much about it. Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. This code throws an error if the filetype is not allowed. Hope this
helps some newbie save a little time.

```
global $post;//http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39753/
if ($_FILES) {
      $files = $_FILES['upload'];
      foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
      if ($files['name'][$key]) {
      $file = array(
      'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
      'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
      'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
      'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
      );


      $uploaded_file_type = $files['type'][$key];
      $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf');
      if(in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
                //if in array run the attachment function
                        $_FILES = array("upload" => $file);
                        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
                        }

        } else { // wrong file type
            $upload_error .= "Invalid File Type. <br />";
            }   
        }
     }
     }
```